# How to create 64bit apk in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to create 64 bit android APk build in react native and I have added abi filters arm64-v8a and x86_64 after this my app Is crashing

Comment: What is your crash report saying? What error are you getting if you log the intents with the command `adb logcat | fgrep -i intent` ?

Answer (score 0):

> React Native supports 64 bit for android starting from version 0.59.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059

First upgrade your react-native version .

Please follow below link this can help you for upgrading your react-native from any older version.
https://pvinis.github.io/purge-web.

Note:  Even after react-native upgrade you are facing the app crash please provide a detailed log.

> This can help you to get detailed log ./gradlew installDevDebug
>   --debug